# Equivalent condition for Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that: $X$ is hausdroff $\iff x=$ intersection of all its closed neighbourhoods.

I could prove the forward implication, using the fact that $X$ is also $T_1$.
So, more generally

$X$ is $T_1 \Rightarrow $ $x$=intersection of all its closed neighbourhoods.

Any ideas for the backwards implication?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct points. If $\{x\}$ is the intersection
of the closed neighbourhoods of $x$, there is one $A$, say, not
containing $y$. The complement of $A$ is open, and so is the interior of $A\ldots$

Comment: How do you know that $x \in $ interior of $A$?

Comment: Related Exercise.  Show a space is T_1 iff for all x, {x} = intersection of all neighborhoods of x.

Comment: @RithwikVidyarthi $A$ is a neighbourhood  of $x$.

Comment: In $\Bbb R$, $[-1,1]$ is not a closed neighbourhood of $1$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is a closed neighbourhood both open and closed'

Comment: Yea. I deleted that comment.

Comment: @RithwikVidyarthi It looks like your confusion is over the definition of neighbourhood. A neighbourhood of $x$ is a set which contains an open set with $x$ as an element.

Comment: Ah...Munkres defines  neighbourhood  of $x$ as an open set containing $x$.

Comment: @RithwikVidyarthi That's what other authors call "open neighbourhoods".

Comment: Thats cleared up then. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly not the case that $X$ being $T_1$ implies that $$\{x\} = \bigcap \{N \subseteq X: N \text{ a closed neighbourhood of } x\}$$

This is shown by the example of $X$ the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$. The only subsets of $X$ that are closed are the finite sets and $X$. But all non-empty open sets are infinite (even cofinite), so  the only closed neighbourhood of any point $p \in X$ is $X$ itself. So the  intersection is just $X$.

Hausdorffness is certainly necessary, for let $X$ satisfy the above condition for every $x \in X$:

Let $x \neq y$ in $X$. As $y \neq x$, then $$y \notin \bigcap \{N \subseteq X: N \text{ a neighbourhood of } x\}$$, so there is some closed neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ such that $y \notin N$. Then $\operatorname{int}(N)$ and $X\setminus N$ are dijsoitn open sets that contain $x$ and $y$ respectively.

On the other hand let $X$ be Hausdorff and let $x \in X$.

Clearly $x \in \bigcap \{N \subseteq X: N \text{ a neighbourhood of } x\}$, so let $y \in X$ be such that $y \neq x$. There are disjoint open neighbourhoods $O_x$ and $O_y$ of $x$ resp. $y$ by Hausdorffness. But then $x \in O_x \subseteq X\setminus O_y $ so the $X\setminus O_y$ is a closed neighbourhood of $x$ that does not contain $y$. So $y \notin \bigcap \{N \subseteq X: N \text{ a neighbourhood of } x\}$ if $y \neq x$. So we have the required identity for $\{x\}$.

Comment: $X$ is $T_1 \Leftarrow $ $x$=intersection of all its closed neighbourhoods Because hausdrofff $\Rightarrow T_1$?

Comment: @RithwikVidyarthi I gave a counterexample. $T_1$ is weaker so why should it imply what the stronger condition implies? $T_1$ implies that $\{x\}$ is the intersection of * all* neighbourhoods, but there are fewer closed neighbourhoods, so these give a potentially larger intersection as the example shows.